# How does $\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(n-k)\lambda} = \sum_\limits{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k\lambda}$?

Tags: limits, summation

How does?

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(n-k)\lambda} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k\lambda}$$

I've tried letting $w = k + 1$ then I get

$$\sum_{w=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(n-w+1)\lambda}$$

It there something basic or some identity I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w=n-k.$ As $k$ goes from $0$ to $n-1,$ then $w$ goes from $n$ to $1.$ You get
$\displaystyle \sum_{w=1}^n \frac 1 {w\lambda}.$

Comment: Alright so then $ 0 < k < n -1 $ and $k = n - w$ sub that into the equality and solve for w I get $w$ from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: @Kevinj22 : When $k=0$ then $w = n$ and every time $k$ increases by $1,$ then $w$ decreases by $1,$ until $k$ gets up to $n-1,$ at which point $w$ has decreased to $1,$ since $n-(n-1) = 1.\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

After cancelling $\lambda$ your left sum is
$$\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n-1} + \cdots +\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{1}$$
and the right
$$\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots +\frac{1}{n-1} +\frac{1}{n} \cdot$$
Now the equality is obvious.
You can formalize this with index manipulation, as shown by Michael Hardy.